# How do I change the background color just for the footer in Figma?

Tags: website-design, figma

I would like the footer's background color to be a different color than the rest of the website. Is there a proper way of doing this or do I just create a rectangle element, stretch it out onto the footer area and change its background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "proper way" of doing this, but there are many ways to accomplish the same result.

You can go as simple as just creating a rectangle and stretching to the size you want for a quick-and-dirty solution.

If you plan to reuse that footer you can turn it into a component and maybe make it Auto Layout, for example.